# Media Foundation playlist plays only the first file from the playlist

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I'm using `IMFSequencerSource` for creating a cut-list of media files. I'm also handling the `MENewPresentation` for queuing the next file. All return values are `S_OK`.
But, when the first file ends, there is no output on the screen. I can see the HDD is still active and the reading is still in progress, but not a single frame on the screen.

Here is a few events from the `Invoke()` method:
MEEndOfPresentationSegment
MF_TOPOSTATUS_ENDED
MESessionNotifyPresentationTime
MF_TOPOSTATUS_SINK_SWITCHED
MF_TOPOSTATUS_READY
MF_TOPOSTATUS_STARTED_SOURCE
So, it seems like the sink is switched and the new source started, but why there are no frames on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs ONLY when I put two file with the same format back to back. So, I guess it's a bug in MS super-super new technology.